# Javascript on localhost doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, localhost

i don't know what is the problem with localhost on Mac Pro , when i want to get a javascript code from a file to html page , it doesn't respond though the javascript work 100%(i checked it by putting it directly in html using  attribute .

Comment: can you print some code?

Comment: When you need help with something that doesn't work, try to be precise; Tell us what you're trying to do, what did not work and any error you got in the console. And more than anything, the code!

Comment: @JacqueGoupil  my bad i am new sorry

Comment: you have a typo when sourcing your controller.js, if that's copy-pasted

Comment: Please note that there may be some same origin policy in effect here.

Comment: i did it doesn't work 
http://localhost/  -- this helped me with the first but the second did not

Comment: @PaulS. could you please explain more ?

Comment: @PaulS.  i am working on a simple html javascript pages 
when i provide the javascript directly in the html page it work with no error , but when i link between the controller.js and index.html it just doesn't work

Comment: Do you event have a server running? We're missing information here. Besides, you shouldn't use `localhost` in an attribute anyway, just reference the file with it's website root path.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil thank you anyway the problem was simple i did not noticed it i wrote scr and not src !!!

Comment: @aaa No problem, be sure to check Thomas' answer as "best answer" when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a typo: `<script scr="controller.js"></script>` -- needs to be `src`.